# How do i get the number of rows in a php mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to use this query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE (Username=" + $username + "AND Hash=" + $hash + ")")
```

to return the number of rows for authentication in a php script. but this doesnt return an int? how do I use the return value to get the number of rows?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to fetch rows from the result:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE ...") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
```

Or since you only need to fetch a single value you can do this more briefly using [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE ...") or die(mysql_error());
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
```

I'd also suggest that you look at parameterized queries instead of building your SQL queries using string concatenations.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that you are using `+` instead of `.` to concatenate strings.

And the values for `username` and `hash` will need quotes around them so they don't break the query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE (Username='" . $username . "' AND Hash='" + $hash . "')")
```

Be sure to add proper error checking to your `mysql_query()` calls as shown in the [manual](http://php.net/mysql_query).

Also be sure you are aware of [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library) for all values, or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($your_resource);
echo (int)($row[0]);
```

Also, you are likely wide open to SQL injection.  You should really learn to do prepared queries with PDO.

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE (Username='" . $username . "' AND Hash='" . $hash . "') LIMIT 1");
$returned = mysql_numrows($result);
echo $returned ." users";
```

However you can optimize the query further more depending on what you are doing with the result set.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php
As well as the http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php and other mysql_fetch_* functions

Also, make sure you format your query properly. Look at mysql_real_escape_strings to escape user input to avoid SQL injection attacks.